# Deploying Solana Smart Contracts In Java

Tags: java, sdk, blockchain, smartcontracts, solana

Can we create smart contracts in Java Programming Language In Solana? I have been studying about it and saw Rust, C and C++ languages. Can we do it in Java?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You cannot write smart contacts in Java on Solana. Only Rust and C are supported at this time.

You can send transactions using the [java SDK](https://github.com/p2p-org/solanaj) though.